# How to call the $firebaseArray in the cloud function of firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, web-applications, google-cloud-functions

So in my angular JS web app, I have a function that calls on a node in the firebase database called `orderedPlayers` and returns it as an array as follows:

```
$firebaseArray(orderedPlayers)
        .$loaded(function(loadedPlayers) {
  // function in here
        });
```

When attempting to do something similar in the cloud function I am experiencing problems. Is there a way to return the the `players` node as an array?

I know i can access the database as follows:

```
admin.database().ref('orderedPlayers');
```

but the `$firebaseArray` doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These docs can help: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

`snapshot.val()` will return an object that can be referenced as a key-value array. In your case:

```
admin.database().ref('orderedPlayers').on("value", function(snapshot) {
  var loadedPlayers = snapshot.val();
  //access your players here
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge cloudfunctions does not include `firebaseArray`. You can instead just make the players *children* into an array.

so:

```
let yourArray = [];
admin.database().ref('orderedPlayers').once('value').then(snap => {
    snap.forEach(childSnap => {
        yourArray.push(childSnap));
    });
});
```

or you can use the children:

```
let yourArray = [];
admin.database().ref('orderedPlayers').on('child_added',snap => {
    yourArray.push(snap);
});
```

*on('child_added') will always be called at least once so it removes the need to loop over the children.

If you want to query the database by a specific value you just add something like `orderByChild('order')` after the `ref` and before calling `once` or `on`

Comment: I think you can use `myArray = snap.val()` Then access all of the data returned from the snapshot as an array